# How to resize a 3D volumes in a Keras network model?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, 3d, image-resizing

I have a 3D volume let's say of (142, 142, 142) size. I expand a dim as a channel because the volume is considered as a grayscale image, so (142, 142, 142, 1).

Then I want to input a batch of these volumes into a Keras model. First, I crop the volume to (32, 32, 32, 1). Then, I need to resize the cropped cube to (48, 48, 48, 1). Therefore I wrote a model like this,

```py
 input_shape = (input_dim, input_dim, input_dim, 1)
 input1 = Input(shape=input_shape, name="input_1")

 cropped = Cropping3D(cropping, data_format="channels_last")(input1)

 resized = Lambda(  
                   lambda cube: K.resize_volumes(cube, 2, 2, 2, data_format="channels_last") 
                  )(cropped)
```

However, `keras.backend.resize_volumes` only allows to input an integer as the resize factor, which means my plan doesn't work this way, because from 32 to 48, the resize factor would be 1.5.

So how can I do the resize as a keras layer? Thanks!!!

Comment: *how* should such a resizing take place? There are algorithms to stretch/resize 2-d images but I am not aware of anything for a 3d volume like this (nor am I really aware of what you mean when you say you have a (32,32,32,1) shape to treat as a greyscale image? `height X width X <what goes here?> * channel`

Comment: @Stewart_R hi, thanks for your questions. Well, perhaps by `resize`, I mean `interpolate` or `resample`. There is such algorithms like `scipy.ndimage.interpolation.zoom` to do the job, while this is not suited in a keras network model. I hope I can do this `resize` inside the network rather than in the preprocess stage for specific reason.

Comment: @Stewart_R As for the shape, I am sorry that I didn't state that clearly enough. The meaning is this, `depth * height * width * channel` or more concretely, `z * x * y * channel`. I will later edit my post based on your concerns.